# I2C not detecting PCF8574

Tags: pi-4, i2c, lcd

What is the issue here? LCD has backpack. Connected following schematic to Pi:

[image]

I2C is not detecting adress of PCF8574:

[image]

Things I have already tried:

- Reinstalling I2Ctools, ensuring I2C is turned on etc
- Changing I2C clock speed (Max for PCF8574 is 100kHz)
- Supplying VCC with 3.3V instead of 5V
- Checking all connections are correct
- Checking I2C functions correctly with another I2C chip, works perfectly fine
- Switching SCL and SDA connections

LCD does light on.

Photos of wiring:
[image]
[image]
[image]
Is there something I'm missing here? Or should I conclude that the backpack is faulty?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You have not made the proper connections.  We need clear photos of the connections you have made.

Comment: @joan I have added the photos as you requested. The connections look fine to me.

Comment: You need to show the Raspberry Pi end of the ribbon cable. The common failure is fitting the ribbon without getting PIN#1 on the cable connected to PIN#1 on your RPi. Check the voltage on the two 5V and two 3V3 pins on your breadboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An I2C Bus needs pullup resistors on the clock and on the data wire. If neither the raspi nor the Backpack attaches these pullups, the bus can not work correctly.

Here is a good intro: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/i2c/i2c-at-the-hardware-level .

I don't see any pullups in your schematics.

Attention: The raspi does *NOT* tolerate 5V, so don't use 5V for the pullups.

If the Backpack does not work with 3.3V (But there is a good chance it does work with 3.3V.) you need a level shifter.

Comment: Take a look at the photos I've added where you can see the backpack and connections. I think there might be pull ups on the backpack but I can't be sure, I'm following a Freenove tutorial that came with the kit that supplied jumpers, lcd board with backpack soldered on etc.

Comment: I found a video on youtube, where the Module was installed on a raspi. They do not use pullups. So I think it should work without. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3XLjVChVgec . On the pictures I saw some VCC and GND  connection from the raspi to another target. Do you use the raspi to power another device too. Perhaps LCD and this board are too much for the little guy.

Comment: I power a small Raspberry Pi fan with it. Just to check, I disconnected the fan and tried again, still no result.

Comment: I don't see any further problems. Perhaps the module is deffect or you did some faulty configuration on  raspi. The following video is from the raspi guy who wrote a autoconfiurator for the usage of these display on a pi. Perhaps it helps. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fR5XhHYzUK0

Comment: I tried following this video and unfortunately it's still not detecting the address in i2cdetect. I think there may be a problem with the backpack soldering.

Comment: Yes, there might be a solder bridge. Another thought: Perhaps the Background LEDs needs too much power which the Raspi can not deliver. But I fear I can not help you from the distance.  Can you measure the Voltage between the VCC and GND pins? If it goes below 5 V than the Raspi can not deliver the needed current. Butin that case I don't understand why it works in the video. If you can, please check also, whether the SDA and SCL connection are powerd with 5V or 3.3V when the raspi is on..

Comment: I measured VCC to GND, 4.65V. I also then tried, without the LCD and fan, SCL to a 10k resistor and then ground, 2.6-2.8v across resistor,  same with SDA, same result. The LED is powered on and shows blocks on the screen, so still not sure, does the same with 3.3v but fainter. When I measure SDA and SCL with LCD, neither shows above 10mV (possibly my multimeter can't read the clock cycles?) I have checked continuity on most of the soldered connections on the backpack, and they seem fine. It must be the chip.

Comment: I just noticed on the photos of the backpack and LCD screen the ground pin plastic insulation at the base of the bin looks slightly damaged, as it does on the LCD board pin - just above it, furthest to the right, where it is connected. It looks like it has shorted there. I'm pretty sure it wasn't me, my Pi didn't trip, and I took extra care to make sure that connections were perfect, especially 5v and ground as I know it can damage the Pi. Perhaps it was shorted by the manufacturer or in testing somehow, which fried the chip? Who knows, I'm now 100% sure the backpack is faulty.

Comment: @Pokebab I don't think the multimeter ist the problem. The SDA and SCL are low active. That means if the I2C Bus does not transmit data, both of them are pulled to 5V or eventually 3.3 V (that depends on the pull up source voltage).  In an idle phase there is no frequency on the lines, just constand VCC. The raspi has no reason to communicate constantly with the LCD, so I think most of the time there is no transmission active.  If you measure <10mV on the lines there is a problem. It might be that the pullup resistors don,t work correctly or the raspi or the LCD/I2C chip pull the lines to low.

Comment: Note that with the possible exception of the compute modules all Pi models have physical 1k8 pull-ups to 3V3 on GPIO 2/3 (pins 3 and 5).  You should not add additional pull-ups and should remove any external pulls to 5V.

Answer (score 2):

I'm now certain there is an issue with the backpack or board.
After further inspection, I noticed that the plastic insulation at the base of the ground pin on the backpack and on the LCD board appear to be damaged. It looks like it was shorted. It could have been me, but I doubt it as I was very careful in wiring, especially as I know the damage that can be caused by shorting 5v and ground pins on the Pi, my Pi seems fine. I believe that the board was shorted prior to my using it, which damaged the chip. I hope.

[image]